# Unable to import MapView in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

imports:

```
from kivy.app import App      
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker

class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        map = MapView(zoom=11, lat=50.6394, lon=3.057, double_tap_zoom = True)
        marker_1 = MapMarker(lon=50.6394, lat=3.057)
        map.add_marker(marker_1)
        return map

MapViewApp().run()
```

error:

```
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 635, in _load_backward_compatible
KeyError: 'kivy.garden.mapview'
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

I installed that

```
pip install mapview
```

Comment: Check the docs again. Its `kivy_garden.mapview`

Answer (score -1):

you should to install

```
pip install kivy-garden 
garden install grapgh
garden install mapview
```